# PrestaShop - How to start working on theme

Tags: php, prestashop

**PRESTASHOP HOW TO WORK ON THEME IN LOCAL SERVER**

Hello Everyone,

i would like to run my prestashop layout on my local server and work on it to see my changes live. I did install xampp, install prestashop on it, and now i want to run my layout on it but i don't really know how. I downloaded all files and database from server to computer but whats next step?

```
**none code**
```

Comment: Well first you would need to install a webserver and PHP on your machine (maybe try XAMPP to get a ready-made environment), then install Prestashop. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/

Comment: you cleared my mind. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I did install xampp and prestashop. Whats next?

Comment: Try and run it? Are you having a specific issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: done. i changed